# Modify text color of QInputDialog

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I need a QInputDialog to enter a name for a file in my program. I have to set my main window as parent, because otherwise the dialog will not appear on top of the window but behind it. But when i set the main application as parent, i get black text on a black background.

So i need to change the textcolor for the label, the textbox and the buttons to white.

I tried using the Stylesheet but cannot figure out what keyword to use.

I tried using QPalette, but that has no effect at all.

```
def setGPKGName(self, mode:int):
    font = QFont()
    font.setFamily("Calibri")
    font.setPointSize(12)

    qm = QInputDialog(self)
    qm.setFont(font)
    #pal = QPalette()
    pal = qm.palette()
    rgb = self.label_text_color.split(',')
    r = int(rgb[0])
    g = int(rgb[1])
    b = int(rgb[2])
    pal.setColor(pal.ButtonText,QColor(255,255,255))
    qm.setPalette(pal)
    qm.setWindowTitle('title')
    qm.setLabelText('Dateiname:')
    if mode == 0:
        if qm.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            return qm.textValue()
    else:
        #this is th way i id it before, but the appearence dosen't fit the rest of the progrm and the dialog appearse behind the main window
        text, ok = qm.getText(None, 'title', 'Dateiname:')
        if ok:
            return text
    return ""
```

If at all possible i would like to use the Stylesheet, but any way o acomplish my goal would be nice.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you use any style sheets in your main window?

Comment: yes. I use them for all components.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be late but,
I had the same problem, the  solution is to set QPushButton as the following

```
qm.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: white; background-color: black; } QPushButton { background-color: #XXXXXX; color: #XXXXXX; }")
```

The `QPushButton` sets colors of the button.

The `QLineEdit` sets colors of the input textbox.

Also, if you are making a file picking window. I suggest using `QFileDialog`

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

app = QApplication([])

options = QFileDialog.Options()
options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File", "", "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)

if filename:
    # filename includes path
    print(filename)

app.exec_()
```